# AWS: How to authorize an API in API Gateway to be called only by Cognito users in a specific group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

In my app, I use the AWS SDK to register users thanks to Cognito and call APIs in API Gateway. In my Cognito user pool, I created a user pool group.

Let's say I have 2 APIs in API Gateway:

- `/test-api-all`, that authenticated users and guest users can call,
- `/test-api-group-only`, that only authenticated users *in the user pool group* can call

I managed to implement the first API thanks to authenticated and unauthenticated roles in Cognito Identity Pool, and by using `AWS_IAM` as authorization mode in the method request.

Unfortunately, I don't manage to properly implement the second API so it can be called only by authenticated users *in the user pool group*...

The closest I got was by following [that post](https://forum.serverless.com/t/is-it-possible-to-control-which-paths-in-apigateway-a-cognito-user-is-allowed-to-call/3532/3):

- create an IAM role for the group, which is the only one that allows to call `/test-api-group-only`
- use `AWS_IAM` as the authorization mode in the method request of the API
- in the Cognito Identity Pool, go to Authentication providers, then below Authenticated role selection, select `Choose role from token` and save changes

Thanks to that technique, `/test-api-group-only` can only be called by authenticated users in the user pool group.

So where is the problem, then? The problem is: if I add an authenticated user to the group (using the AWS console for example), the user still has to wait up to an hour so he can call the API... because it's based on the access token. This is definitely not what I want if, for example, the user just paid to call that API.

What's the right way to implement `/test-api-group-only`, even if the user has just been added to the group?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: When the user pays, and is successfully added to the group, refresh their credentials with the refresh token... They'll then receive new ID and Access Tokens.

Comment: @hephalump Thank you very much, I'll try that.

Comment: possibly; what language are you using?

Comment: AWS SDK for Android, but I'm also taking a quick look.

Comment: Good luck! Feel free to message if you get stuck.

Comment: OK, I'm stuck: I tried `AWSMobileClient.getInstance().refresh()`, but it has no effect...

Comment: Either `AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getTokens();` or `AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getTokens().getIdToken().getTokenString();` should return refreshed credentials.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it's not the case: all tokens are exactly the same before and after I call `AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getTokens().getIdToken().getTokenString();`.
And according to what I read, it looks like this feature is not implemented yet... for some reason.